# Getting values inside square brackets in C with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

This function extracts from the input message that begins and ends with square brackets, the contained message and inserts it into out.

So if input = [message] then out = message

```
int stringInsideSquareBracket(const char *in,char *out)
{
    /*
        %*[^[]  read and discard everything until it finds a square bracket
        [       read and discard the first square bracket
        %[^]]   read and store up up to (but not including) the closing square bracket
        %*[^\n] read and discard up to (but not including) the newline
    */
   return sscanf(in, "%*[^[][%[^]]%*[^\n]", out);

}
```

The problem I am experiencing is on a message of type [12.0;34.0;78.0]. The function does not insert anything in out. I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Since you're reading from a string, do you really need the last `%*[^\n]` part?

Comment: I believe if there's nothing before the opening bracket that `%*[^[]` will fail.

Comment: And personally I would rather use `strchr(in, '[')` to find the opening brace, then use that returned pointer to get the closing `]` the same way, and then copy the string in between.

Comment: @Antonio, do you really what to tolerate/ignore any text before the `'['`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Everything I need is inside the brackets

Answer (score 2):

> The problem I am experiencing is on a message of type [12.0;34.0;78.0]. The function does not insert anything in `out`

Scanning fails the initial `"%*[^[]"` part as nothing was scanned from `"[12.0;34.0;78.0]"`.  Scanning then stopped.   `sscanf()` returned 0 and unfortunately code did not check the return value before using `out`.

```
//          v----v  Fails this part.
sscanf(in, "%*[^[][%[^]]%*[^\n]", out);
```

Save time, check return values.

---

```
// %*[^[]  read and discard everything until it finds a square bracket
%*[^[]  read and discard everything until it finds a square bracket, at least one non-'[' must be found.
```

---

Advanced:

It is poor code design to save to a destination without knowing its size.  Recommend

```
int stringInsideSquareBracket(const char *in, size_t out_size, char *out)
```

---

Rather than use `sscanf()`, consider `strchar()`.

```
// Return length of substring.
// Return -1 when not found or out[] too small.
long stringInsideSquareBracket_alt(const char *in, size_t out_size, char *out) {
  char *left = strchr(in, '[');
  if (left) {
    char *right = strchr(++left, ']');
    if (right) {
      size_t substring_length = right - left;
      if (out_size > substring_length) {
        memcpy(out, left, substring_length);
        out[substring_length] = '\0';
        return substring_length;
      }
    }
  }
  if (out_size > 0) {
    out[0] = 0;
  }
  return -1;
}
```